# Jquery date picker is not working in angular after navigate to a different component and come back to the same component

Tags: jquery, angular

I am using jQuery DatePicker in an Angular project. The date picker is working when I load the component. However after I navigate into a different component and come back to the same component, then date picker is not working. Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this issue?.

The below code part was entered in a component which has the date picker.

```
ngOnInit() {
  (<any>$("#txtDepartDate1")).datepicker();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using a jQuery plugin in your angular project. there are lots of angular options available, https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview or you can try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-date-picker

Comment: Put this in ngAfterViewInit

Comment: @KamranKhatti. Thank you for the reply. I added under ngAfterViewInit. But when I navigate same component, date picker is not working.

Comment: @AtulRajput. Thank you. I want to display a two-month calendar. I will check the bootstrap to have a two-month calendar.